# Is ANCOVA suitable/scientifically sound for my case?

Tags: ancova, predictor

I have a question regarding the suitability of co-variate.

I have three groups with different levels of production in pcs (low, medium, high), material waste in % and number of machine setup changes.

Can I use the number of machines setup changes as a co-variate, if in majority of cases high level of production is related to nigher number of machine changes?

I am almost certain that its not suitable as they are usually correlated (although it does not have to be the case), but needs external opinion and explanation.

If co-variate is not suitable, whats do you recommend me?

Thanks

Comment: If you add the number of machines as covariate, then the group differences will be the expected group differences if they had the same number of machines. But if the different groups had different number of machines, then the comparison and group difference from ANCOVA is invalid because machines in different groups never had the same number of machines.

Comment: @Heteroskedastic Jim. Thank you for your time to post. However, now I am confused even more by your answer, and feel even more, that ANCOVA is not suitable.I will try to explain a little bit more. There is only one machine. In the real data, there are up to 5 machine set up changes, which means converting the same machine to produce, different brands. Now, higher machine setup changes usually means higher production and subsequently production in group "high" will have more machines changes, than the one in group "low". In this scenario how suitable is ANCOVA?